# Expected exposed port on Redis container isn't reachable, even after binding the port

Tags: docker, redis

I'm having a rather awful issue with running a Redis container. For some reason, even though I have attempted to bind the port and what have you, it won't expose the Redis port it claims to expose (6379). Obviously, I've checked this by scanning the open ports on the IP assigned to the Redis container (172.17.0.3) and it returned no open ports whatsoever. How might I resolve this issue?

Docker Redis Page (for reference to where I pulled the image from): https://hub.docker.com/_/redis/

The command variations I have tried:

```
docker run --name ausbot-ranksync-redis -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 -d redis
docker run --name ausbot-ranksync-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
docker run --name ausbot-ranksync-redis -d redis
docker run --name ausbot-ranksync-redis --expose=6379 -d redis
```

https://gyazo.com/991eb379f66eaa434ad44c5d92721b55 (The last container I scan is a MariaDB container)

Comment: A colleague of mine floated the idea it could be a firewall issue. I am almost certain it isn't after looking at the protocols it seems that the firewall is not the issue of this dilemma: https://gyazo.com/428c8105e6f2a00ed983d1c1d1771fea

Comment: Did you try all these command at once?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, I didn't. Ran each one, ensuring the docker container was up, I would then checks the logs. After that, run nmap on the designated IP. If it didn't work I would stop & remove the container, then move onto the next command.

Comment: Very well. Wouldn't you happen to know the issue of my problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/ Tried a couple of your commands, they did what they're supposed to. So, not a problem with docker, this one.

Answer (score 0):

> The command variations I have tried:
>
> ```
> docker run --name ausbot-ranksync-redis -p 127.0.0.1:6379:6379 -d redis
> docker run --name ausbot-ranksync-redis -p 6379:6379 -d redis
> ```

Those two should work and make the port available on your host.

> Obviously, I've checked this by scanning the open ports on the IP assigned to the Redis container (172.17.0.3) and it returned no open ports whatsoever. How might I resolve this issue?

You shouldn't be checking the ports directly on the container from outside of docker. If you want to access the container from the host or outside, you publish the port (as done above), and then access the port on the host IP (or 127.0.0.1 on the host in your first example).

---

For docker networking, you need to run your application listening on all interfaces (not localhost/loopback). The official redis image already does this, and you can verify with:

```
docker run --rm --net container:ausbot-ranksync-redis nicolaka/netshoot netstat -lnt
```

or

```
docker run --rm --net container:ausbot-ranksync-redis nicolaka/netshoot ss -lnt
```

To access the container from outside of docker, you need to publish the port (`docker run -p ...` or `ports` in the docker-compose.yml). Then you connect to the host IP and the published port.

To access the container from inside of docker, you create a shared network, run your containers there, and access using docker's DNS and the container port (publish and expose are not needed for this):

```
docker network create app
docker run --name ausbot-ranksync-redis --net app -d redis
docker run --name redis-cli --rm --net app redis redis-cli -h ausbot-ranksync-redis ping
```